# Inrease heap memory allocation for java application

Tags: java, memory-management

Running java application in IntelliJ and profiler shows heap memory full. Is there a way to increase heap memory allocation?
[IntelliJ profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewp4w.png)

I tried already https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html. However my default was 2G but changing to 16g profiler shows the same.

Comment: The second page you linked to explicitly states that it is only for setting the memory for the IDE, not the application. It even states how to change it for the application itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't help because you changed heap memory allocation for IntelliJ, not for your application. If you want to increase memory for application, add following VM option to your application configuration:

```
-Xmx16g
```